# Unknown error inserting in table in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to do a class to access a database in Sqlite3 in Python 3.
The database was created and when I check if its inserting on the database I get the following error on the second line of the **init** method:

```
File "~/implementacao 2/Dabase_Connection.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.insert_in_database('database_name.db','table_name', '(\'111\',\'qqqq\')')
  File "~/implementacao 2/Dabase_Connection.py", line 33, in insert_in_database
    c.execute('INSERT INTO '+ table_name + ' VALUES ( '+ data +' )')# Insert a row of data
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

The code is this one:

```
def __init__(self):
        # self.create_database('database_name.db', 'table_name', 'id TEXT, data TEXT')
        self.insert_in_database('database_name.db','table_name', '(\'111\',\'qqqq\')')
        # self.delete_from_database('database_name.db', 'table_name', 'data1')
        # self.update_in_database('database_name.db','table_name', 'data', 'data_nova', 'data1')
        # self.insert_all_in_database('database_name.db', 'table_name', [('data1','data1'),('data2','data2'),('data3','data3'),('data4','data4')])
        # self.Search_in_database('database_name.db', 'table_name', 'data')


def create_database(self,database_name,table_name,table_args):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE '+ table_name + '(' + table_args + ')')# Create table
    conn.commit() # Save (commit) the changes
    conn.close()# We can also close the connection if we are done with it.

# INSERT INTO prontuarios VALUES(id,prontuario);
def insert_in_database(self,database_name,table_name, data):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO '+ table_name + ' VALUES ( '+ data +' )')# Insert a row of data
    conn.commit() # Save (commit) the changes
    conn.close()# We can also close the connection if we are done with it.

def delete_from_database(self,database_name,table_name, chave):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('DELETE FROM ' + table_name +' WHERE Id= '+ chave +' ; ')# Insert a row of data
    conn.commit() # Save (commit) the changes
    conn.close()# We can also close the connection if we are done with it.

def update_in_database(self,database_name,table_name, table_field, data, chave):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('UPDATE ' +table_name+ ' SET ' + table_field + ' = ' + data + ' WHERE id = ' + chave+' ;')# Insert a row of data
    conn.commit() # Save (commit) the changes
    conn.close()# We can also close the connection if we are done with it.

# persons = [("Hugo", "Boss"),("Calvin", "Klein")]
# Fill the table conn.executemany("'"insert into person(firstname, lastname) values (?, ?)", persons)

def insert_all_in_database(self,database_name,table_name, data):
    data_interrog = self.get_parameters(data)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.executemany('insert into ' + table_sifnature + ' values ( '+ data_interrog +' ) ', data)
    conn.commit() # Save (commit) the changes
    conn.close()# We can also close the connection if we are done with it.


def Search_in_database(self,database_name,table_name, fields):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
    c = conn.cursor()
    # Print the table contents
    for row in c.execute('select '+ fields + ' from ' +table_name):
        print(row)
```

Comment: Don't bother with hand made SQL. Use an ORM (SqlAlchemy leaps to mind) or if this is a webapp, Django

Comment: This is not a Web app its just to save my files in a DB to keep  my algorithm it faster

Comment: then use SQLAlchemy

Comment: Print your generated SQL, you'll see the problem. If not, edit you question and add the printed query.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your parameter for data, if you print the generated sql, it is not in correct format, it will be:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( ('111','qqqq') )
```

Change your second line to:

```
self.insert_in_database('database_name.db','table_name', '\'111\',\'qqqq\'')
```

or:

```
self.insert_in_database('database_name.db','table_name', "\'111\',\'qqqq\'")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Your code is vulnerable to Sql Injection!

The python pages quote say something like:

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python
> variables. **You shouldn’t** assemble your query using Python’s string
> operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program
> vulnerable to an SQL injection attack

As mentioned in other comments, I **strongly** recommend you use an ORM like [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) instead of writing bare sql queries like you did.

---

I usually use something like this when I'm trying to connect to to an `sqlite3` db:

```
class SqliteDB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        self.db_path = os.path.join(self.parent_directory, 'db.sqlite3')
        self.db_connection = sqlite3.connect(self.db_path)
        self.db_cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()

    def execute(self, query, args=''):
        return self.db_cursor.execute(query, args)

    def commit(self):
        self.db_connection.commit()

    def close(self):
        self.db_connection.close()
```

Based on the above class, you can easily build the other methods you need (`update`, `delete` etc).

Comment: So How to I do the Crud operations and how I call this method Im new on Python